# Saving JSON hash value as decimal - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, bigdecimal

I'm trying to save an amount that is sent via JSON to my postgreSQL database in a decimal column.

The hash looks something like this:

```
{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"network"=>"BTCTEST", "address"=>"2MstFNxtnp3pLLuXUK4Gra5dMcaz132d4dt", "available_balance"=>"0.01000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

And the particular piece of data that I am saving is the: `"available_balance"=>"0.01000000"`

The problem that I have is that the amount saves as:  `#<BigDecimal:74b44d8,'0.0',9(18)>`

In my controller to extract and save the amount I have:

```
@deposit['data']['available_balance']
Payment.update(amount: @deposit['data']['available_balance'])
```

Is there something else that I need to add or change for the amount to save as `0.01000000`? The amount saved fine when the column was a string, however, I need to do some calculations/maths with the amount.

Any comments or assistance will be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to convert your BigDecimal to a float, which you can do with

```
@deposit['data']['available_balance'].to_f
```

[Beware the dangers of floating point arithmetic](http://www.rails-troubles.com/2011/12/ruby-float-quirks.html), however, [especially when dealing with money](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/).